# Saving richTextBox from tabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I save the specific richTextBox in the selected tab if I have several tabs with a richTextBoxe in everytab? The application is a text editor, and when I try to save the text of richTextBox in selected tab, my application does not have access the text in richTextBox which is in a selected tab. How can I do that? I have searched a lot. But no answer found!! Thank You!

Comment: What does "save" means? save to file? save in memory? Please be more specific. And what error you receive when trying to access `richTextBox1.Text` ?

Comment: @etaiso : saving in a file. I have a save button and I want to when it pressed, the text of the richTextBox that is in selected tab(I have several tabs with richTextBox in), saves in a file.

Comment: ok, what about my seconds question? And please provide some code.

Comment: @etaiso : There is a new button too. when I press it, a new tab with a richTextBox in, adds. I can not access to the richTextBox in selected tab to save it's text. Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' does not contain a definition for 'richTextBox1' and no extension method 'richTextBox1' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TabPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\God\Desktop\Project\Project\Project\Form1.cs 91

Comment: OK, now that I can see the error, please attach the erroneous code (edit your question, do not paste in comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the mapping in a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<TabPage, RichTextBox> richTextBoxs = new Dictionary<TabPage, RichTextBox>
                                   {
                                       {tabPage1, richTextBox1}, 
                                       {tabPage2, richTextBox2}
                                   };
```

And access the dictionary to get the corrosponding richtextbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      RichTextBox richTextBox = richTextBoxs[tabControl1.SelectedTab];
      label1.Text = richTextBox.Text;
}
```

**Edit**

This is an updated code considering you have to save the text into file.

```
richTextBoxs = new Dictionary<TabPage, Tuple<RichTextBox, StreamWriter>>
                                   {
                                       {tabPage1, new Tuple<RichTextBox, StreamWriter>(richTextBox1, new StreamWriter("1.txt"))}, 
                                       {tabPage2, new Tuple<RichTextBox, StreamWriter>(richTextBox2, new StreamWriter("2.txt"))}
                                   };
```

And save to file on button click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tpl = richTextBoxs[tabControl1.SelectedTab];
    tpl.Item2.Write(tpl.Item1.Text);
}
```